# Отличия <br> от <p></p> тегов

Tags: html

Собственно вопрос в заголовке - оба тега вроде делают одно и тоже, когда же лучше использовать `<br>` а когда `<p></p>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<br>` и `<p>` делают совершенно не одно и то же.

`<p>` используется для обозначения параграфа (абзаца) текста, в то время как `<br>` - для создания отступа между строками/переноса текста на другую строку.

Вообще, в современных реалиях использовать `br` вообще не рекомендуется (кроме тех случаев, когда вам необходимо разделить **текст**). Все отступы делаются при помощи стилей. По крайней мере, *должны*.

Судя по всему, автор вопроса спрашивает про различие пустого `<p></p>` и `<br`.

Здесь дело в том, что по умолчанию браузер добавляет тегу `p` 2 отступа: один размером 1em снизу и один такой же сверху. Если текста внутри тега нет, то остается только один отступ, равный 1em (то есть как раз высоте одной строки текста грубо говоря).

Но `br` не создает *отступа*. Он *переносит строку*.

И тут нетрудно догадаться, что отступ размером в одну строку текста и одна пропущенная строка текста будут одинаковы по высоте (ну или почти). Так что, по сути, **пустой** `p` и тег `br` делают одно и то же, но совершенно разными путями, это да.

Ключевое же отличие у них в семантике: тег `p` используется для обозначение одного абзаца текста (а отступы - побочный эффект стандартной стилизации, от которого можно избавиться в одну строку CSS кода), а тег `br` используется именно для *переноса строки*.

Так что использовать `<p></p>` для создания отступа не стоит. Если вам нужно отделить одну часть *текста* от другой, воспользуйтесь `br`. А если вам нужно отделить друг от друга какой-то визуальный контент, используйте CSS отступы (различные).

```html
<p>
Здесь идет текст. Тег p используется для того, чтобы обозначить абзац текста.<br>
Но здесь текст написан в том же абзаце, но уже на новой строке.
Конечно, можно поставить несколько тегов br:<br><br><br>
Ставлено 3 тега br: первый перешел на новую строку, второй и третий сделали то же самое, в результате чего было пропущено 2 строки.
<p></p>
А выше вставлен пустой тег p, который визуально сделал то же самое, что и один br, но семантически совершенно неверно. Дальше будет вставлен еще один тег p, но отступы у него будут убраны стилями, в результате чего отступа вы не увидите:
<p style="margin: 0;"></p>
Текст после тега p с убранными отступами.
</p>
```

Comment: Но ведь можно обернуть абзац в Br. например так : <Br/> Новый абзац и текст<Br/>

Comment: @Сергей нет. `br` не имеет закрывающего тега

Comment: Я имел в виду что два тега добавят отступы как перед так и после текста новую строку и видимость в  браузере будет такой же как и с P и P/

Comment: @Сергей а, вот оно что. Ну здесь вы тоже ошибаетесь, поскольку "отступы" у тега `p`, назначаемые браузером по умолчанию выполнены в виде `margin`'ов. А `br` создает именно пустую строку текста.

Comment: @Сергей добавил сниппет для наглядности.

Answer (score 3):

`<br/>` - это перенос строки. Тег `<p>` - создание параграфа(абзаца). таким образом в тег `<p>` должно содержаться текст с законченной мыслю, а `<br />` - служит просто для переноса текста на новую строку.

Размер отступа у них разный. Тег `<br/>` - он больше годен в использовании внутри тегов таких как `<p>, <td>`...

Во многих визуальных редакторах новая строка обозначается как `<p></p>` - для удобности работы визуальных редакторов, а не потому что так правильно

Comment: т.е. разница только в логике ? что внутри P может находится много Br/ ?

Comment: @Сергей, Верно.

Comment: @Node_pro верно? Нет, не верно. Разница не только в логике. Разница во всем: и в синтаксисе, и в семантике, и в логике.

Comment: @smellyshovel но смысл то не в том что бы делать новый тег с новым синтаксисом и семантикой но оставлять ту же логику. Тег br может заменить p так что разницы в браузере не будет?

Comment: @Сергей нет, тег `br` не может заменить `p`, еще раз повторяю. А разница для браузера всегда есть, иначе зачем вообще было создавать все эти разнообразные теги? Ограничились бы парочкой, что уж там.

Comment: @Сергей, будет но на внешний вид, не значительная. Да и зачем использовать для пустой строки тег, какой не предназначен для этой функции, если есть специальный тег, какой для этого сделан (Br)

Comment: @smellyshovel `иначе зачем вообще было создавать все эти разнообразные теги` вот и мне не совсем понятно )) т.е. br это аналог Еnter в браузере, а P дает именно отступ и этот отступ в отличии от br можно регулировать стилем. Правильно ?

Comment: @Сергей вы, что ли, используете просто `<p></p>` без текста внутри?

Comment: Нет, аналог Enter - это как раз P. А br - это аналог Shift+Enter. P делит текст на абзацы, а br делит абзац на строки.

Comment: @smellyshovel Я вообще HTML в работе еще ни разу не использовал. но всегда хочется научится новому. поэтому пытаюсь понять этот нюанс.

Comment: @Сергей уже дополняю свой ответ. Обновлю через пару минут.

Comment: @smellyshovel благодарю